# How can I optimize and combine these inefficient database queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Here's are my DB queries:

User has_many UserFollow (UserFollow is a relationship between User models).
User has_many Photos.
Photo has_many PhotoFollow relationships (PhotoFollow is a relationship between User and Photo models).

```
@user_list = Array.new
user_followers = UserFollow.where("user_1_id = ?", current_user.id).includes(:follower)
user_followers.each do |f|
  @user_list << f.user
end

photos = Photo.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).includes(:follow_relationships => [:photo])
photos.each do |p|
  p.follow_relationships.each do |f|
    @user_list << f.user if !@user_list.include? f.user
  end
end

if @user_list.size < 150
  users = User.where("verified = ? and first_name IS NOT NULL and last_name IS NOT NULL", true).includes(:solutions).limit(150 - @user_list.size)
  users.each do |u|
    @user_list << u if !@user_list.include? u
  end
end
```

All of this takes a ridiculous amount of time obviously. Using includes helps, but I am wondering if there is some way to more efficiently do this set of operations.

Thanks,
Ringo

Comment: Am I reading this wrong? If you're looking to combine those three result sets, won't that be every single user because of query 3?

Comment: please see edited! Yes - I do want every single user, but I want them in that specific order. I have decided to limit step 3 to max 200 users, but there are other complications now (performance issues basically)

Comment: First see how long the queries actually take. That is see what Rails is sending to the database and try executing the queries with out Rails. My guess is your loading all these objects and then facing N+1 select problem. See if you can make a **real SQL** query that gets everything you want and see how long it runs.

Answer (score 2):

Append your associations first.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follows_to_user, :class_name => 'UserFollow', :foreign_key => 'follower_id'
  has_many :follows_to_photo, :class_name => 'PhotoFollow', :foreign_key => 'user_id' # if you don't have it now
end
```

Now, first two queries you can make much more elegant within **just one SQL query**, returning **AR::Relation** scope.

```
@user_list = User.includes(:follows_to_user => {}, :follows_to_photo => {:photo => {}}).where(["user_follows.user_1_id = :user_id OR photos.user_id = :user_id", :user_id => current_user.id])
```

About 150... [updated]

Of course you'd better to implement that logic appending the previous SQL statement with conditions and **UNION** statement (using **SQL syntax** only), that should return AR::Relation and will be a little faster. But you can stay lazy and leave it in ruby, although it will return **Array**:

```
if (count = @user_list.count) && count < 150 # run COUNT just once and store value into local variable
  @user_list |= User.where("verified = ? and first_name IS NOT NULL and last_name IS NOT NULL", true).includes(:solutions).limit(150 - count)
end
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can simplify: User.includes(:follows_to_user => {}, :follows_to_photo => {:photo => {}}) to User.includes(:follows_to_user, :follows_to_photo => :photo)

Comment: yeah, but I like the old syntax, think it much more understandable. imho

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a better way then my answer, but why don't you include `:user` since you're loading them when iterating over your queries?

```
@user_list = Array.new
user_followers = UserFollow.includes(:user).where("user_1_id = ?", current_user.id)
# why did you include followers?
user_followers.each do |f|
  @user_list << f.user
end

photos = Photo.includes(follow_relationships: { photo: :user }).where("user_id = ?", current_user.id)
photos.each do |p|
  p.follow_relationships.each do |f|
    @user_list << f.user unless @user_list.include? f.user
  end
end

if @user_list.size < 150
  users = User.where("verified = ? and first_name IS NOT NULL and last_name IS NOT NULL", true).limit(150 - @user_list.size)
  # why did you include solutions?
  users.each do |u|
    @user_list << u unless @user_list.include? u
  end
end
```

Maybe this is faster, I'm not sure:

```
@follower_ids = UserFollow.where("user_1_id = ?", current_user.id).pluck(:user_1_id).uniq

@photo_ids = Photo.joins(follow_relationships: :photo)
@photo_ids = @photo_ids.where("user_id = ? and user_id not in (?)", current_user.id, @follower_ids)
@photo_ids = @photo_ids.pluck(:user_id).uniq

@followers = User.where("id in (?)", @follower_ids)
@photo_users = User.where("id in (?) and not in (?)", @photo_ids, @follower_ids) 

@array_size = (@follower_ids + @photo_ids).size
if @array_size < 150
  @users = User.where("verified = ? and first_name is not null and last_name is not null", true)
  @users = @users.where("id not in (?)", @photo_ids + @follower_ids).limit(150 - @array_size)
else
  @users = []
end

@final_array = @followers + @photo_users + @users
```

I haven't tested if this works, or if it's faster. It has more database queries but less iterations.

#### Update

What if you added another column to the users model that gets updated with a value from 1 to 3, depending on whether they have followers, photos, or nothing.

Then all you would need to do is:

```
# in User model
def self.valid_users
  where("verified = ? and first_name is not null and last_name is not null", true)
end


@users = User.valid_users.order("sortable ASC").limit(150)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you're planning on getting a list of users to your `@user_list`. You can build up the list of user ids first so we don't create unnecessary AR objects

**First code**

```
@user_list = Array.new
user_followers = UserFollow.where("user_1_id = ?", current_user.id).includes(:follower)
user_followers.each do |f|
  @user_list << f.user
end
```

can be changed to

```
# assuming you have a user_id column on user_follows table
user_ids = User.joins(:user_follows).where(user_follows: { user_1_id: current_user.id })
  .uniq.pluck('user_follows.user_id')
```

**Second code**

```
photos = Photo.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id).includes(:follow_relationships =>[:photo])
photos.each do |p|
  p.follow_relationships.each do |f|
    @user_list << f.user if !@user_list.include? f.user
  end
end
```

can be changed to

```
user_ids += Photo.where(user_id: current_user.id).joins(follow_relationships: :photo)
  .uniq.pluck('follow_relationships.user_id')
```

**Third code**

```
if @user_list.size < 150
  users = User.where("verified = ? and first_name IS NOT NULL and last_name IS NOT NULL", true).includes(:solutions).limit(150 - @user_list.size)
  users.each do |u|
    @user_list << u if !@user_list.include? u
  end
end
```

can be changed to

```
user_ids += users = User.where(verified: true)
  .where('first_name IS NOT NULL AND last_name IS NOT NULL')
  .where('id NOT IN (?)', user_ids)
  .limit(150 - user_ids.size).pluck(:id)
```

Then you can just fetch all the users using `user_ids`

```
@user_list = User.where(id: user_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess.

```
@user_list = current_user.followers.where("verified = ? and first_name IS NOT NULL and last_name IS NOT NULL", true).includes(:solutions, :photos => {:follow_relationships}).limit(150)
```

Over all I think its all wrong due to the complexity alone. If you cant read what its doing clearly then you should start over again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up table indexes for your tables?

If you haven't yet, set them up for all of your foreign keys and for columns that you need to include in your conditions. In your DB migration script (with your correct table and column names, of course). They will speed up your queries, especially if you have a large dataset:

```
add_index :user_follows, :follower_id
add_index :user_follows, :followed_id

add_index :photos, :user_id

add_index :photo_follow_relationships, :photo_id
add_index :photo_follow_relationships, :follower_id

add_index :users, :verified
add_index :users, :first_name
add_index :users, :last_name
```

Also, some comments and recommendations:

```
# ... [SNIP] Query and add to user list.
user_followers = []  # You are not actually using the UserFollow records. Unload
                     # them from memory. Otherwise, they will be stored until we
                     # leave the block.

# There is no need to fetch other Photo data here, and there is no need to load
# :photo for FollowRelationship. But there is a need to load :user.
photos = Photo.where(:user_id => current_user.id).select('photos.id').
    includes(:follow_relationships => [:user])
# ... [SNIP] Add to user list.
photos = []  # Unload photos.

# ... [SNIP] Your condition.
# There is no need to load :solutions for the users here.
users = User.where("verified = ? and first_name IS NOT NULL and last_name IS NOT NULL", true).limit(150 - @user_list.size)
# ... [SNIP] Add to user list.
```

It would, of course, be nicer if you refactor the code too, as in some of [mind blank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211372/mind-blank)'s recommendations. You can also manke use of [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) associations too to clean up your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following relationships to your models

```
class User  
  has_many :user_follows
  has_many :inverse_user_follows, :class_name=>'UserFollow', :foreign_key=>:follower_id

  # followers for user
  has_many :followers, :through => :user_follows
  # users followed by user
  has_many :followed_users, :through => :inverse_user_follows, :source => :user


  # photos created by user
  has_many :photos

  has_many :photo_user_follows, :through => :photos, :source => :user_follows

  # followers for user's photo

  has_many :photo_followers, :through => :photo_user_follows, :source => :follower


  has_many :photo_follows
  # photos followed by user
  has_many :followed_photos, :source => :photo, :through => :photo_follows

end  

class UserFollow
  # index user_id and follower_id columns
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Photo related models

```
class Photo
  # index user_id column
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :photo_follows
  has_many   :followers, :through => :photo_follows
end

class PhotoFollow
  # index photo_id and follower_id columns
  belongs_to :photo
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Now you can get the users who are current users followers OR current user's photo followers OR active users..

```
user_ids = current_user.follower_ids | current_user.photo_follower_ids

User.where("ids IN (?) OR 
   ( verified = ? and first_name IS NOT NULL and last_name IS NOT NULL )", 
  user_ids, true).limit(150)
```

Comment: Three SQL queries... and the third one is wrong. He wants to append the scope to 150 followers _only_ if it's less (no more followers found). In your example you fetch just the first match records with combined conditions.